# How do you delete the last message in a specific channel?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to delete the last post in a specific channel. i found nothing about it on the internet. Can anyone help me?

Comment: How didnt you find anything on the internet? Just search for the [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome). There you can easily find [how to get the latest message of a channel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=lastMessage) and [how to delete a message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=delete)

Comment: Missing information in your question. please try to give a more detailed information when asking a question so the answer will be relevant to what you are trying to reach. furthermore, if you are looking for something in the internet, it will be great to describe what specific data you used while you did your search?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```js
channel.lastMessage.delete();
```

or

```js
guild.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL_ID').lastMessage.delete();
```

to get the channel by it's ID.

---

Docs:

[channel.**lastMessage**](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=lastMessage)

[message.**delete**](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete)

Comment: @SimonDeRuyver Maybe include a snippet of your code? That error should not be possible if you have properly defined `channel` or `guild`

Comment: I got this guild.channels.cache.get ('CHANNEL_ID'). LastMessage.delete (); and I got this UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' or undefined error.